# Qt 5.8 QTableView Header Color won't change

Tags: qt

I can't seem to get the color of the Header in a QTableView. I've tried lots of different things, but none of them seem to work. I could use some help.

Here's my code:

```
tableView = new QTableView;
tableView->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                         "border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                         "gridline-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                         "background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"
                         "QHeaderView::section { background-color:black }");
```

I'm open to any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer to this question was in the other answers, but they also contained misleading code (on my machine, anyways: Win7x64).

Here's what worked and what didn't (again, for me).

This code did nothing to the header:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");
```

This code worked but also changed the border of the whole QTableView Widget:

```
tableView->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { 
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}");
```

This code worked as expected:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color: rgb(40, 0, 0) }");
```

This code also worked, a variant on the one above:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("::section { background-color: rgb(40, 0, 0) }");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any `QHeaderView::section` directive that can be used within the context of the style sheet for the containing view (e.g. `QTableView`, `QListView` etc.).  I think you need to set the `QHeaderView` style sheet explicitly...

```
tableView = new QTableView;
tableView->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                     "border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                     "gridline-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"
                     "background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);");
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This had no effect, unfortunately. I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the fact that there is no header until this code is called: "tableView->setModel(model);"

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. According to the official docs, it must work properly.

The [QSS HeaderView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview) directive defines the properties for the `QHeaderView` class:

```
tableView->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { 
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}");
```

As alternative, you can modify directly the `QHeaderView` section properties:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("::section { 
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}");
```

If you want to change the background of the whole header, use:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, my code does not work properly and neither do any of your suggestions. I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the fact that there is no header until this code is called: "tableView->setModel(model);"